# Running multiple sudo commands

Tags: unix, sudo

How does one provide a password only once when running multiple long-running sudo commands in a bash for loop? For example I have a command like this:

```
for DATE in 20120902 20120903 20120904 20120905; do; sudo -u ...; sudo -u ...; sudo -u ...; done;
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if you have multiple sudo commands, like below

```
for DATE in 20120902 20120903 20120904 20120905; do
    sudo echo $DATE;
    sudo echo $DATE;
    sudo echo $DATE;
  done;
```

it should only prompt you for the root password once.  sudo starts a session where it leaves you machine exposed for like a minute or something (probably configurable somewhere).  If you machine isn't behaving like this, then maybe you can configure it to do so.